# Angular Reactive Forms - Adding dynamically group elements - radio buttons issue

Tags: angular

I'm building a course manager and now I'm working on the course creation.

I'm trying to add dynamically to my reactive form an array and the array contains radio buttons to select the day.

And I have a button to add more elements (the same radio button choice of the Day of the week) to the array.

Everything works good but when I'm selecting a radio button. it removes the selection from the other arrays as well (the value stays the same but the dot of the selection getting deleted)

[code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gz9n8a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Please click the buttong 'Add item' and then try to choose the radio button of the first array and than the second.

The button is dissapearing...

I dont really know how to solve it

I will be more than happy if someone could please take a look at the code.

Comment: Read this: [ask]. And start including some code in the post and not just a link to the code. [mcve] is what is expected.

Comment: remove the `name` attribute to yours inputs type=radio" (in html when a input type radio has the same name only can select one of them)

Comment: @Eliseo Thank you ! But if i remove the name attribute than the timesArray becomes undefined

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you, the timesArray value is in `this.courseForm.value.timesArray` and the timesArray is `this.courseForm.get('timesArray') as FormArray`, check your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-o8upyp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). I add a `<pre>{{courseForm?.value|json}}</pre>` at the end